# Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Failed

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, cmake-gui

I'm currently getting this error while trying to configure a project on CMAKE using Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.11.25547.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.11.25547.0
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Found OpenGL: opengl32  
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - not found
Found Threads: TRUE  
Using Win32 for window creation
Using WGL for context creation
Lib glbinding
Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Failed
Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED
Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED - Success
Configuring done
```

I've used this compiler to generate another project and it still works. 
Here is the code relevant to the new CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(ms3d_td3)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.0)

add_subdirectory(ext/glfw)
add_subdirectory(ext/glbinding)

include_directories(ext/glfw/include)
include_directories(ext/glbinding/include)
include_directories(ext/eigen3)

if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()

set(SRC_FILES 
    src/main.cpp
    src/viewer.cpp
    src/viewer.h
    src/shader.cpp
    src/shader.h
    src/opengl.h)

add_definitions(-DDATA_DIR="${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data")

add_executable(ms3d_td3 ${SRC_FILES})

target_link_libraries(ms3d_td3 glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} glbinding)
```

Under Visual Studio 2017 I get a CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set after EnableLanguage. I tried to set it manually to the VisualStudio 2017 compiler but no success. Any ideas?

Another person had a similar problem and solved it by upgrading Visual Studio a while ago so I'm guessing this is coming from somewhere else... :

[Compiler failing on C++11 instructions in a Visual Studio project configured with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624885/compiler-failing-on-c11-instructions-in-a-visual-studio-project-configured-wit)

Thanks!

Comment: [VS2017 does support deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes2) so maybe the detection is not up to date?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly I also tried configuring cmake with visual studio 2015 but with no success =/

Comment: It looks like [this test](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/GenerateExportHeader.cmake#L221) is checking for `__attribute__((__deprecated__))`, not `[[deprecated]]`.  If you need to know if `[[deprecated]]` is supported by your compiler, you can always write your own compiler check following a similar approach to the one linked.

Answer (score 0):

To require compiler support for the `[[decprecated]]` attribute, use [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html?highlight=target_compile_features) and specify the [`cxx_attribute_deprecated`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html) feature.  For example:

```
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
target_compile_features(foo PRIVATE cxx_attribute_deprecated)
```

If you need to conditionally test for this so that you can configure a header file, use [`check_cxx_source_compiles`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCXXSourceCompiles.html).